# Should I use rich snippets for news list and detail?

Tags: schema, article, structured-data, rich-snippets

I use the normal rich snippets / structured data code "`<article itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">`" for my news list and there is, for example, Image, H3, P-Tag and the a-hrefs for the detail page. It is a News-Short-Teaser.

On the news detail page, as you can read in the Google documentation, I use the normal rich snippets news code: "`<article class="article" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">`..."

Therefore the question is whether you can also see the rich snippets in the news list, where the news is only teased, or only on the news detail page?

Many thanks for your help.